# Layout issues in android

Tags: android, layout

I am developing application in Native Android. I have custom ads displayed on multiple screens. When I navigate from one screen to another banner looks fine. But suddenly while navigating banner size changes. 
Note : the implementation of layout are same as it banner looks fine on same tab multiple times but suddenly it changes its distentions.

Please see the following images [image]

[image]

Here is my ads layout. Note : Banner ads are coming from backend.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >    
 <RelativeLayout 
   android:id="@+id/rl_add"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#000000"
   >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/iv_ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"           
        android:layout_height="@dimen/add_height"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And using webview properties I am displaying those ads.

Comment: Resize the image to smaller size and repost question, as it poses  problem for slow internet users !

Comment: Please post your layouts xml.

Comment: please post all the code you are using to display the ads

Comment: Let me guess... Maybe you used "wrap content" for the footer's height, instead of a fixed value?

Comment: Please look at the question...I have added the code.